# Can a Java class have an instance of type itself?

Tags: java, class, oop, conceptual

I came across a code snippet as below, for implementing a linked list:

```
public static class Element<AnyType> {
    private AnyType data; 
    private Element<AnyType> next; // reference to the next node
    Element(AnyType d, Element<AnyType> e) {
        data = d;
        next = e;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how this is possible? How can a Java class (in my case Element) have an instance variable of its own type?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's throwing you off. Why do you think it *shouldn't* be able to happen?

Comment: Here `AnyType` is a generic type; and it's quite possible for a class to contain a reference to an instance of its' own type.

Comment: This isn't C++; `Element<AnyType>` having an instance variable `Element<AnyType> next` doesn't mean that the memory layout of an `Element` has to physically encompass the memory layout of another `Element` ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

> How can a Java class (in my case Element) have an instance variable of its own type?

Actually it doesn't.  Java only has primitive and reference variables, not instances.  This means `next` is a just a **reference** which is initially `null`.

```
private AnyType data; // a reference to an AnyType object
private Element<AnyType> next; // reference to the next node
```

BTW The comment does state it's a reference not an instance.

Why is there no special symbol like in C++? because in Java there is no other option so no reason to have a `&` or similar.